# Red Laser Safety Filters?

Tags: optics, safety, lasers

First of all, apologies if this is the wrong SE site.

Last year I bought a k40 laser cutter and it came with a square orange/red acrylic safety filter, which is meant to be used for looking through when observing the laser at work.

What I don't understand is that the laser beam (40W CO2) is in the infra-red,  and I would have thought that the visible light from the cutting would be black-body radiation (red through to white) so why use a orange-red filter - which appears to dim everything except for the cutting edge?

I would have thought that an IR cut-off filter would have a blue hue.

Should I just throw this away and get myself some IR cut-off safety glasses?

[image]

Comment: You can't trust a filter's effectiveness by colour. It's not even in the spectrum you can see. And we're talking long IR which is well removed from the visible spectrum. Look at the colour of IR laser safety glasses. It's all over the place from nearly clear blue to green to orange brown. Our brain does not interpret wavelengths independently. The sky might look blue but there is a lot of green wavelengths in there. Get safety glasses too but keep that filter...if it's real it was expensive...

Comment: I went and bought some OD 6+ 190nm-450nm / 10600nm anyway. Thanks for the thoughts.